# Critical and Inflection Points with Stochastic Processes

Tags: derivatives, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

In normal calculus without stochastic processes, we look at $\frac{df}{dx} = 0$ to calculate critical points and $\frac{d^2f}{dx^2} = 0$ to calculate inflection points. For example, given function

$$f(x)=x^3-x$$

We can derive the critical points:
$$f(x)=3x^2-1=0 \implies x=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

And we can derive the inflection points:
$$f(x)=6x=0 \implies x=0$$

What is the equivalent of a critical point and inflection point in ito calculus? What additional information do we need about the error term? For example, say we have the function

$$f(x)=x^3-x + \epsilon$$

How would you calculate the critical points and inflection points analytically? What about empirically if we did not know this specific function was what we were looking at?

**Edit**: Revised incorrect $x=1,0,-1$ critical points.

Comment: First of all the critical points of $f(x)=x^3-x$ are $x=\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ not $1,0,-1$...

Comment: Next, if $g(x)$ is differentiable, and $\epsilon$ is an RV functionally independent of $x$, then $f(x)=g(x)+\epsilon$ has the same critical points as $g(x)$. For $f'(x)=0$ if and only if $g'(x)=0$ since differentiating $\epsilon$ with respect to $x$ under our assumption of functional independence will result in a vanishing term. But this is probably a triviality...

Comment: Finally, if, e.g., $f(t)=t^3-t+B_t$ where $B=(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a standard Brownian motion, then $f(t)$ is not differentiable with respect to $t$ since $B_t$ is not differentiable anywhere for $t\in [0,\infty)$. So standard calculus methods definitely will fail. You may or may not get some mileage out of weaker notions of derivatives but I can only point to some keywords like "distribution theory" and "distributional derivative"

Comment: In the case you describe with $f(t)$, could we appeal to Malliavin calculus?

Comment: I haven’t studied much Malliavin calculus so I cannot say, sorry. Hopefully someone wiser stops by.